# How to pinchzoom imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, pinchzoom

I would like to pinchzoom an imageview in android but can't do that. 
I can't find any tutorial. How can i solve this problem?

Like this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftKgMGnzUAc

Answer (score 1):

Use [the ImageViewTouch library](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) which is published on GitHub under an MIT license. It lets you load a bitmap with any zoom setting and then the user can use common gestures, including pinch, to pan/zoom it. Very easy to set up. I used it in several places in my app. So far as I know there's no "out of the box" support for pinch zoom in the Android libraries.

Comment: thanks. i have found this its work really good maybe it can help you too http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/